# How to remove a deleted subdomain website from Google Search?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, subdomain, technical-seo

I made a website in the past on my website's subdomain. But when I saw that all the posts and pages on that subdomain became indexed in Google Search, I was shocked. I didn't want the subdomain to be indexed.

I already removed the website from the subdomain, now I want to know how to remove all the results for that subdomain from Google Search.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify things, you'll want to start by making sure the DNS entry (`A` or `CNAME`) for your subdomain is deleted, which basically deletes the subdomain from your domain name. This will ensure that no pages can remain as stragglers, because there will no longer be any server responding at all to requests for your subdomain. This is all you need to do to get your URLs to drop out of search organically.

However, if you want to expedite the process, you could try submitting a Removal in Google Search Console. Using [this related post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59018/) as a guide, you should be able to do the following:

1. Add and verify your subdomain `https://badsubdomain.example.com` in Google Search Console (use the "DNS" verification method, since there is no server there anymore to verify by different means.)
2. Visit the "Removals" tab, and find the "Temporary Removals" tool.
3. Enter `https://badsubdomain.example.com` for the removal request, since you want to remove the whole thing.
4. Check "Remove all URLs with this prefix".
5. Submit.